# Inject Javascript to a website using Apache

Tags: apache

I have a website that I want to add Javascript to the header part of the HTML using Apache i.e. without touching the code.

My client requires us to add a layer of Apache which will add some code to the HTML.

Is there any Apache module that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache [mod_include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/mod/mod_include.html) with [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) helps you

Comment: But in both cases i need to add lines of code to exiting code manually.